# customize linux shell prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

In my `.bashrc`, I got this:

```
PS1="[\w $]"
```

And every time when I `cd` to a dir with a deep level, the shell prompt almost takes up the whole line, (terminal size: 80*24), like:

```
[/level_a_dir/level_b_dir/level_c_dir/level_d_dir/level_e_dir $]
```

**Question**

I want to cut the prompt short if the `pwd` is longer than 20 chars, just keep the last dir, like:

```
[.../level_e_dir $]
#[/level_a_dir/level_b_dir/level_c_dir/level_d_dir] is replaced with ...
```

How to do it?

Comment: Bash already offers the `\W` prompt escape for this.

Comment: There's also `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`, but that's not precisely what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it in the following way.
First you have to create a shell script, truncate.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAXLEN=20
REPLACEMENT="..."

# replace /home/user by ~
TPWD=$(echo ${PWD} | sed 's#'${HOME}'#~#;')

# truncate
if [ ${#TPWD} -gt ${MAXLEN} ] ; then
  PWDOFFSET=$(( ${#TPWD} - ${MAXLEN} ))
  TPWD="${REPLACEMENT}${TPWD:${PWDOFFSET}:${MAXLEN}}"
fi

echo ${TPWD}
```

Next you have to replace your PS1:

```
export PS1="[\$(truncate.sh) ] "
```

Comment: Each time when a new prompt cropped, the `truncated.sh` will be executed once, right? Does it me, if I just simply push `Enter` in the command-line, the `truncated.sh` will get executed?

Comment: @Alcott Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Each time a new prompt is generated (after a command has finished or after an `Enter`) truncate.sh will be executed.

Comment: You got that right, :-). Could you plz explain `sed 's#' ${HOME} '#~#;'`, I don't quite get it.

Comment: @Alcott `${HOME}` contains your home directory (`/home/alcott`). To save some characters I replace it by `~`. That means: `/home/alcott/Documents` becomes `~/Documents`. (similar to: `sed 's#/home/alcott#~#;'`; syntax: `sed 's#pattern#replacement#;'`)

Comment: You could use `case $PWD in ${HOME}/*) PWD='~'"${PWD#$HOME}";; esac` to do the substitution entirely with shell built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want **just** 20 characters whetever that might be (or less), then the simplest I can think of is:

```
export PS1='[${PWD:$((${#PWD}-20))} $]'
```

I would drop the brackets if you don't have much space or think about having a two line prompt (which I personally hate :-)